# Azure offline data sync performance

Tags: ios, azure, mobile, offline, data-synchronization

We are considering using Azure offline data sync for our app which usually has very sporadic connectivity (In most cases users sync their data once a day). Thing is that mobile app needs to hold a lot of data (tens of thousands of products). Currently we have our own sync solution which works fine with sqlite.

My question is, do you have any experience or thoughts about performance of Azure offline data sync? Will it be able to handle really large datasets?

Thanks you

Comment: The Mobile Services Offline SDK leverages SQLite so you should find performance / behaviour as you have today.

Answer (score 0):

Azure mobile service is the cloud version of popular Microsoft sync framework. This is a light weight json API which tracks changes between local and remote data store. It transfers only changed rows, hence data traffic will be minimum. But when you sync very first time and you have huge data, it might be a problem.

You could overcome this problem by carefully designing your database structure. Azure SDK provides api to sync table by table, which gives you enough flexibility to choose what to sync and not.